# Duplicate values in a table rows GoogleSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the scenario. I have two tables:

Table 1:

```
ID | Elem1 | Elem2 | Elem3     | Elem4
---+-------+-------+-----------+-----------
1  | PP1   | NN3   | NN17      | dsfposakfd
2  | PP2   | PP345 | PP9398    | ghitru
2  | PP2   | PP854 | uafsf     | NN3
3  | NN17  | PP64  | dsfjjsdf  | liw
4  | NN17  | PP64  | podjfsojk | eu
5  | NN3   | PP100 | poasdio   | oej
6  | PP4   | PP126 | [sdfo[pso | NN17
```

Table2

```
Elem
-----
PP3
NN17
PP2
```

What I want my output to be is either:

Result table

```
Elem | ID
-----+---------
PP3  | 1,2,5
NN17 | 1,3,6,4
```

or

```
Elem | ID
-----+---------
PP3  | 1
PP3  | 5
PP3  | 2
NN17 | 1
NN17 | 3
NN17 | 6
NN17 | 4
```

How could I do that?

Comment: What engine do you use (e.g. T-Sql, My-Sql, etc...) and does the order of the result matter?

e.g.  `NN17 3,4,1,6`  is equivalent to `NN17 1,3,6,4` for your purposes?

Comment: No, It does not - MySQL Please note the change from NN to PP. I only did it because I did not know what you could see so I made a couple of screenshots.The Idea is the same. Thanks for the help.

Comment: replace your images with text!

Comment: I answered you below. However, for future questions, I think it is preferable to use text instead of images (as you did before) because in that way I was able to copy your data, format it quickly and get an ready-to-use test case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this query:

```sql
SELECT t2.Elem, GROUP_CONCAT(ID) as Ids
FROM tab t
JOIN tab2 t2 ON t2.Elem IN(t.Elem1, t.Elem2, t.Elem3, t.Elem4)
GROUP BY t2.Elem;
```

If you don't want duplicated Ids for the same Elem use this:

```sql
SELECT Elem, GROUP_CONCAT(ID) as Ids
FROM (
    SELECT t2.elem, t.ID
    FROM tab t
    JOIN tab2 t2 ON t2.Elem IN(t.Elem1, t.Elem2, t.Elem3, t.Elem4)
    GROUP BY t2.Elem, t.ID) R
GROUP BY Elem;
```

And last but not least if you want to see each element of table `tab2` even if not present in `tab` you can switch the JOIN and use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```sql
...
FROM tab2 t2
LEFT JOIN tab t ON t2.Elem IN(t.Elem1, t.Elem2, t.Elem3, t.Elem4)
...
```

Obviously, replace `tab` and `tab2` with the name of your table and the column name `Ids` with `ID` if you prefer (but personally I prefer the plural because in this column you can find more than one ID)